# mocha beforeEach is not running

Tags: solidity, solc, mocha

beforeEach hook is not running. THis is a strange error, I googled but did not find anything. For anything strange, I delete node-modules and reinstall and it works but this time it did not work.

```js
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

var { abi, evm } = require("../compile.js");
const bytecode = evm.bytecode.object;
const abi_string = JSON.stringify(abi); // convert object to string
// those are defined
console.log("Abistring", abi_string);
console.log("bytecode", bytecode)

let accounts;
let lotteryInstance;
// beforeEach(async () => {
beforeEach(async function () {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  lotteryInstance = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi_string))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });
  console.log("lotter", lotteryInstance);
  console.log("something");
});

describe("Lottery", async () => {
  console.log("lottery", lotteryInstance);
  console.log("printing");
});
```

I placed 2 console statemenst inside beforeEach, but they do not log anything. Since beforeEach hook is not running,  `console.log("lottery", lotteryInstance)` is logging undefined.

There is nothing with compile.js file. Everthing is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beforeEach will get executed at before every it() function in mocha.so you have it() fn in your code as shown in code snippet below

```
describe("Lottery", async () => {
it('test1',async()=>{
    console.log("lottery", lotteryInstance);
    console.log("printing");
}) });
```